# Is modifying a List in this manner bad practice?

Tags: c#

In Class A(What will output the List if it is not empty):

```
private List<int> _myList = new List<int>
public List<int> MyList {get{return _myList;} set{_myList = value;}}
```

In Class B:

```
public bool MyClassBMethod(stuff)
{
     //stuff
     try{
          something
     }
     catch(Exception){
         ClassA.MyList.Add(stuff);
         return false;
     }
     return true;
}
```

Is editing a List like this bad practice? Or is it okay?

Edit: I am only adding to the list as such when my method needs to return something else(bool, object, string, etc).

Comment: Looks OK to me. What are you concerned about?

Comment: What do you mean "like this".  From another class?  Via a property?  Via the Add method?

Comment: Is Class A a `public static` class?  Or how else are you accessing `MyList` in Class B?

Comment: use auto getters and setters `public List<int> MyList {get;set;}` There isn't a reason to declare the public/private variables like the old days.

Comment: Whoah... the edit you just did *totally* changes things here...

Comment: If someone sets your list to null, then you will now have an unhandled exception in your catch block, which they can do of course because the set is public. Even with a public get and private set the caller basically has full control over your list. It all depends really!

Comment: Well, looking at your edit ... things change. This code is REALLY ugly. One of the things, don't return true or false to handle errors, use try/catch ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a class should be responsible for managing its own internal state. By giving full public access to a member like this, you are basically saying that Class A is giving up responsibility of that part of its state. It cannot make assumptions about what _myList contains because anyone could change that at any time.

Whether that's good or not depends on what your intent is, but it certainly runs contrary to the ideas of decoupling and encapsulation. Again, whether you *want* decoupling and encapsulation is up to you.

A better question would be to determine what sort of decoupling between classes A and B would be most beneficial to your design, and then you'd be able to decide what member to expose and how.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't normally do that.

You are exposing a very large interface to the clients of your class, making it difficult to test that your class works in all situations. What happens if someone removes values when you aren't expecting it? Or what if they add a value that is out of range? You can't validate it at the time they call the method on your `List`, so your class might just suddenly break at some later point in time when it might be difficult to trace where the bad data came from.

It's better to have an `Add` method on your class that calls the list's `Add`, and keep the list private. Then you can control what your clients do, and only expose the functionality they need to use (and that you've tested).

Comment: Don't agree at all. This is a really common way of interacting with lists in the .Net framework.

Comment: @SoMoS: Can you give an example of a class in the .NET framework that exposes a `List<T>` as a public property?

Comment: WPF Observable collections. You're always showing them in this way.

Comment: Not a list but a IList, a IEnumerable or a ICollection, in the context of the question is the same.

Comment: Exposing an `IEnumerable<T>` is not **at all** the same as exposing a `List<T>`. I wouldn't have a problem with `IEnumerable<T>`, as long as it makes sense for the situation of course.

Comment: Anyway take a look at the simple WPF button - properties CommandBindings, InputBindings, Triggers, etc. All of them are Collections.

Comment: So you don't have a problem exposing a IEnumerable<T> but do have with IList<T>?

Comment: @SoMoS: The question is about `List<T>` not `IList<T>` or `CustomCollection<T>`. There are many, many more [methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4) on `List<T>` than there are on [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ywykzh6). `IList<T>` is designed to be used as interface. `List<T>` is not. I can see you aren't going to change your mind. I think we'll just have to agree to disagree on this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common practice. What is not so common is to have the set public. Make it private, initialize the list on the A constuctor and you're all set.

```
public ObservableCollection<int> MyPublicList {get; private set;}
```

WPF is full of declarations like this one.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends. If the list is intended to be edited outside of the class (it is part of the interface for that class) and all of the regular list operations are allowed, it is OK. If only a subset of operations are allowed then you should't use it like this - use a custom list (or wrapper around your list) that enforces all of the constraints. For example, if the list must be read-only outside of the class then you could provide a [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) wrapper outside of the class. It all comes down to enforcing data integrity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you care about whether the list is exposed or not.  By exposing & accessing a public, concrete type, you are exposing an implementation detail and increasing the coupling between the class and its consumers.  You are also limiting `ClassA`'s opportunities to enforce data consistency, since its implementations details are no longer encapsulated properly.

Sometimes, this is perfectly acceptable, sometimes, it is not.

I'd say it's acceptable in cases where the object model is dumb.  By dumb, I mean that it just contains data.  Situations like this often occur when parsing JSON / XML to objects -- things are structured to mirror the data, and behaviour doesn't really matter much, as there's very little of it.  It's also more acceptable if you're just hacking away in a small codebase and/or there is limited scope for change, or there is very little behaviour involved.

I'd usually avoid it, though.

Firstly, imagine that the items you add to `ClassA`'s list must be prime numbers.  You could easily enforce this check if you write an `AddItem()` method, but it becomes much harder to do effectively if the list is publicly exposed.

Secondly, suppose you decide to change the list to be a dictionary.  You will now likely break the calling code sites (`ClassB`, for one), as they were previously relying on an implementation detail of `ClassA`.  If, instead, you created methods called `AddItem()` and `RemoveItem()` or similar for `ClassA`, `ClassB` wouldn't care whether the internal implementation is a Set, Dictionary or List etc, nor would it break when the changes are made.

Guidelines surrounding 'Dotting into things' (like `blah.List[3].GetProduct(3).Reviews.First()`) has a name: [The Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

The salient point of The Law of Demeter is:

> The fundamental notion is that a given object should assume as little
> as possible about the structure or properties of anything else
> (including its subcomponents).

You often have to write more code, but it insulates against change.